# Concatenate text with Currently selected item in WPF Combo box without affecting data binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, wpf-controls

This is my sample XAML code for combobox

```
 <ComboBox x:Name="cboPerson" SelectedIndex="0"
ItemsSource="{Binding PersonCollection}" 
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

All I want to do is to concatenate a string (say 'Default') to the currently selected item in the combo box. But, this shouldn't reflect back in the data object 'SelectedPerson'.

This is just to let the user know as what is the currently selected person when combo box is expanded.

If I intend to concatenate this in viewmodel object SelectedPerson, it actually ends up in modifying the underlying data. So, I just want to show up a concatenated string in Combox box only for the selectedItem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson, Mode=TwoWay,` **TargetNullValue=Default** `}"`. HTH

Comment: Did you try to use StringFormat? SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson, Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat={}{0} (default)}"

Comment: @nkoniishvt Nope. This doesn't work. I tried it even before posting this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a DataTempalte to achive this by using a data trigger on the IsSelected property of the combobox item:

```
  <ComboBox>
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate >
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="Default: " Name="txtSelected" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ComboBoxItem}}" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="txtSelected" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```